# Updating Subversion from PHP on Windows - Permissions-related (Access Denied)

Tags: php, svn, iis, windows-server-2008

I have written a PHP script which updates a SVN working copy.

It works fine on my development machine (W2k3 Server)but I cannot get it to work on a production server (W2k8 Server). I'm using the latest Collabnet Subversion binaries (1.6.17).

Here's the PHP code:

```
$command = 'svn update C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite --config-dir C:\Windows\Temp'; 

$response = array();
$handle = popen("$command 2>&1", 'r');
$read = '';
while( $read = fread( $handle, 20096 ) ) 
{
    $response[] = $read;
}
pclose( $handle );
flush();

echo '<h2>Command</h2><p> ' . $command . '</p>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><p>' . implode( '<br />', $response ) . '</p>';
```

When I run the same command from the command prompt it works fine. But when I run it through IIS, I get:

> svn: Can't open file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.svn\lock': Access is denied.

Presumably I need elevated permissions but I have no idea how to implement it.

I've tried giving the _IUSR account full control of the folder containing svn and the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.svn\ folders but it makes no difference.

Thanks

Comment: `full control of the folder` recursively or not? Can you check who owns file `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.svn\lock` and `whoami` for discovery of IIS/PHP user/group ?

Comment: When you say you run the same command from the command prompt, and it works. Are you running it as your IIS identity or as yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had issues just like this with SVN and Windows Server 2008. The issue is caused by the UAC stuff that typically prevents someone from changing a file if they don't own the file. In the case of SVN, the issue was typically that one user performed the initial checkout, creating the .svn folders and associated bits. Then a different user went to `svn up` and got OS-level access issues about modifying the SVN database files.

Unfortunately, the best fix we could get to was disabling UAC. Actually solved a few other problems and it really makes sense on servers. If it is running as a scheduled task then you could try "run with highest priviliges" but elevating that much makes little sense for a web app.

Comment: Please do not do this on a production box! UAC is the heart of security on a Windows system. While it can be inconvenient at times, It is very important for a secure server to have fine grained permissions. And please remember, Full Control is the same as 777 on a Unix box! Please take the time to set permissions to correct levels on servers for your own good!!

Comment: There is a huge difference between disabling UAC and granting full control to everyone. UAC is a layer on top really meant for user-facing things where nothing should not write to other people's files, but it has some issues on servers. Like this one.

Comment: I was trying, unsuccessfully I see, to make that distinction. I am sorry if you misunderstood me. I was referring to part of the question that said he was giving an internet user account full control to his entire SVN folder. I was trying encourage the questioner to start with the smallest, least potentially dangerous change. Then if that doesn't solve the problem, add permissions one at a time, incrementally. In other words don't use a sledgehammer to swat a fly.

Answer (score 2):

- Account IUSR_COMPUTERNAME must have read/write access to the folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.svn` if it is a checkout.
- Next (not sure), you may need to give **write access to the folder in the IIS properties** for the virtual folder `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.svn`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specifically grant read/write permissions to the user that PHP is running under.  In my case php is running as an Apache module, so it runs under the same account. I am less familiar with your setup, however the basic idea is the same. Once you have determined what account you are running PHP under, grant it write permissions to the lock file and your problem should go away.

**I DO NOT recommend disabling UAC on a production server!! EVER!!!** You want to grant the smallest amount of permissions for the smallest number of users to the smallest amount of resources necessary.

**DO NOT remove all of your user account security to write to a lock file!!!** Instead, grant the single permission write. Not full control. Grant it to the single user who needs it (likely the local system account). Grant it for the specific file(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite.svn\lock) which it needs to write to.

**This approach keeps you from opening a security hole that could be exploited by the malicious!**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. In the end all these answers helped.

I needed to do several things:

- Performed a svn cleanup
- Turned of UAC if access is denied when setting permissions
- The top level .svn folder needed write permissions for IIS_IUSR
- All .svn folders need Read/Write permissions for the Users group.
  However, there's no apparent way to do this, so the permissions need to be set
  on the whole site directory.

After which the PHP script was able to perform an svn update command. Phew!